# Using trap with KDB and non-declared variables?

Tags: kdb

Say for example I'm trying to do try-catch where `x` does not exist:

```
@[x;::;"error"]
```

I get an `'x` error, rather than `"error"`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation here https://code.kx.com/q/ref/apply/#trap
"In the ternary, if evaluation of the function fails, the expression is evaluated"

The function x cannot be evaluated as it does not exist. The function is not failing here it just cannot be called. The hint here is in evaluated - we can use value to check if the function exists.

```
q)f:{x+x}
q)@[value;`f;"error"]
{x+x}
q)@[value;`p;"error"]
"error"
```

The returns of values on the defined function f vs something that is not defined p >

```
q)value f
0x6161410003
,`x
`symbol$()
,`
5 3 4 2 2
"..f"
""
-1
"{x+x}"
q)value p
'p
  [0]  value p
             ^
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `value` keyword to determine if a variable exists or not. Error trapping this might be what you're looking for?

```
q)@[value;`x;"error"]
"error"
q)x:12
q)@[value;`x;"error"]
12
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that using `value` on the variable name will only work if the variable you're checking for is global, it would not work for a local variable:

```
q){@[value;`v;"error"]}[]
"error"
q){v:9;@[value;`v;"error"]}[]
"error"
```

Though in reality in most cases you would be looking for a global so this will work.

If it was a local you were looking for then things get a bit hacky and messy, but technically possible:

```
q){locals:?[(`$())!();();();{x!x}raze(value .z.s)1 2];$[`v in key locals;locals`v;'"error"]}[]
'error

q){v:9;locals:?[(`$())!();();();{x!x}raze(value .z.s)1 2];$[`v in key locals;locals`v;'"error"]}[]
9
```